# Put the cursor in the center of the screen in emacs

Tags: cursor, point

How can I jump to the center of the screen with my cursor. I tried M-x because it was described as the solution, but that is of course already taken by the function search.

Is there an easy way to do this in emacs like the L key in vim.

Comment: Specify clearly what behavior you're requesting - e.g. just what the `L` key in Vim does, and just what you mean by "center of the screen": beginning of vertically center line in a window (not screen)? horizontally centered on that line? or on the current line?

Comment: Do you mean `M`? :help M -> To Middle line of window, on the first non-blank character linewise.

Comment: "I tried M-x because it was described as the solution" -- Where?  To which description/solution are you referring?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default in Emacs, the <kbd>M-r</kbd> key is bound to `move-to-window-line-top-bottom` which, I think, does what you want. It jumps to the beginning of the center line of the current window.

If you invoke it multiple times in a row, the point will cycle through center, top, and bottom. The `recenter-top-bottom` command, bound to <kbd>C-l</kbd> by default, is similar, but scrolls the whole window.

Comment: I use recenter-top-bottom all the time, but it's C-l here and I think that's default.

Comment: @JasonHunter You are right, this was a mistake, thank you.